# MS Access - display repeating rows once with the highest value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013, jet

I have 2 tables in MS Access with the following values

```
Customer
id | name 
1  | jon  
2  | bob
3  | jack

Order
id | amount | date        | customer
5  | 50     | 3/10/2017   | 1
4  | 100    | 3/10/2017   | 1
3  | 45     | 2/28/2017   | 2
2  | 10     | 3/10/2017   | 3
1  |  5     | 3/10/2017   | 2
```

I want to get an output of

```
name  | orderid | amount
jon   | 5       | 50 
bob   | 3       | 45
jack  | 2       | 10
```

I want to get amount of the latest order id per customer, however I keep getting this

```
name  | orderid | amount
jon   | 5       | 50 
jon   | 4       | 100
bob   | 3       | 45
bob   | 2       | 10
jack  | 1       | 5
```

I used the query designer and have used the function MAX() to the order id, GROUP BY to all columns (MS Access does not allow to group the rows using a single column), DISTINCT and DISTINCTROW, as well as set the query properties "Unique Records" to Yes but the duplicate records still shows.

Comment: Do you want to see just the latest order for each customer? What do you want to happen if there are two orders from the same customer on the same date?

Comment: @SunKinght0 yes, I want to get the latest order for each customer. If there are two order from the same date, I want to get the latest or the highest order id

Comment: I will try to provide some help when time permits. Are your Order IDs sequential? Is it a guarantee that a newer order will always have a higher Order ID? In that case you just need a sub query that gets the Max(order.id) grouped by customer ID and link that to your two tables.